# Resumable.js: HTTP response errors (deployed to heroku or nodejitsu)

Tags: http, node.js, heroku, response

I've been experimenting with resumable.js and I've been very happy with the performance of its built-in node.js server on my laptop.  However, it dies on anything over about 1MB when I deploy it to heroku or nodejitsu and get this error:

> Poorly formatted HTTP response (heroku)

or

> {"bytesParsed":9,"code":"HPE_INVALID_STATUS"} (nodejitsu)

How can I fix this so I can deploy?

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "uploader-resumable",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  },
  "subdomain": "blahblah",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "app.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm replying to this unanswered question because of its high search-rank when you search for the HPE_INVALID_STATUS error, even though it is a little old.

This error may occur when you're passing an invalid status code with the HTTP response from within nodeJS without checking for a valid status code, for instance an object instead of a number. (I've seen a lot of HTTP/1.1 [Object object] responses pass by when i was helping someone to debug this behaviour ...)

Answer (score 0):

> Poorly formatted HTTP response

is a specific response code returned from Heroku. Nodejitsu shouldn't be showing that error.

see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h17-poorly-formatted-http-response

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  I'll add to lines to the question.  Nodejitsu says:
{"bytesParsed":9,"code":"HPE_INVALID_STATUS"}